# How to add svg polygon triangle inline?

Tags: css, html, svg

I tried to add four svg polygon triangle inline. but i couldn't do it. can anyone help me?

here is the code i tried.

```
<svg viewBox = "0 0 500 500">   
    <polygon points="195,140 245,210 140,210" style="fill:red;"></polygon>
    <polygon points="195,140 245,210 140,210" style="fill:red;"></polygon>
    <polygon points="195,140 245,210 140,210" style="fill:red;"></polygon>
    <polygon points="195,140 245,210 140,210" style="fill:red;"></polygon>
</svg>
```

this is the image which i want to create.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually had your 4 triangles, but placed them **all at the same place**.

Modify your points, something like :

```
<svg viewBox = "0 0 500 500">   
    <polygon points="195,140 245,210 140,210" style="fill:red;"></polygon>
    <polygon points="295,140 345,210 240,210" style="fill:red;"></polygon>
    <polygon points="395,140 445,210 340,210" style="fill:red;"></polygon>
    <polygon points="495,140 545,210 440,210" style="fill:red;"></polygon>
</svg>
```

**Demo :** https://jsfiddle.net/Paf_Sebastien/rn9wtzjf/